# Best way to pad a vector with zero bytes?

Tags: rust

I need to send some messages (as vectors), and they need to be sent as the same length. I want to pad the vectors with zeros if they are not the right length.

Let's say that we need all payloads to be of length 100. I thought I could use the `extend`function and do something like this:

```
let len = 100;
let mut msg = &[1,23,34].to_vec();
let  diff : usize = msg.len()-len;
let padding = [0;diff].to_vec();
msg.extend(padding);
```

This won't compile though, since the compiler complains that `diff` is not a constant. But also this seems rather verbose to do this simple thing that we are trying to.

Is there a nice and concise way to do this?

Comment: FWIW `[0;diff].to_vec()` aside from not working (because the size of arrays must be known at compile size) is overly complicated: the `vec!` macro can take a runtime size, so `vec![0;diff]` would have done the job. Though Chayim's answers are still much preferable.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can fix your code with `std::iter::repeat()`:

```rust
let len = 100;
let mut msg = vec![1, 23, 34];
let diff = len - msg.len();
msg.extend(std::iter::repeat(0).take(diff));
```

But there is much better way - [`Vec::resize()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.resize) is what you need:

```rust
let len = 100;
let mut msg = vec![1, 23, 34];
msg.resize(len, 0);
```